# One class file works for other class file. It does not process properly

Tags: php, mysql

here is config.php

```
<?php 
define('DB_DSN','mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sales');
define('DB_USERNAME','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define("TBL_MEMBERS",'member');
define('TBL_PURCHASE','purchase');
define('TBL_SALES','sales');

?>
```

this is dataObject.class.php

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
abstract class DataObject{
protected $data=array();

public function __construct($data){
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $this->data))
            $this->data[$key]=$value;
    }
}

public function getValue($field){
    if(array_key_exists($field, $this->data)){
        return $this->data[$field];
    }else{
        throw new Exception("Field is not found", 1);

    }
}

public function getValueEncoded($field){
    return htmlspecialchars($this->getValue($field));
}

protected function connect(){
    try {
        $conn=new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT,true);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Connection failed", 1);

    }
    return $conn;
}

protected function disconnect($conn){
    $conn='';
}


} 


 ?>
```

Here is my customer.class.php file

```
<?php 
require_once("DataObject.class.php");

class Customer extends DataObject{
protected $data=array(
    'id'=>'',
    'customerName'=>'',
    'totalPrice'=>'',
    'date'=>''
    );

public static function getCutomers($startRow,$numRows,$order){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS*FROM ".TBL_SALES." ORDER BY $order LIMIT :startRow, :numRows";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":startRow",$startRow,PDO::PARARM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(":numRows",$numRows,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $purchases=array();
        foreach($st->fetchAll() as $row){
            $customers[]=new Customer($row);
        }
        $st=$conn->query("SELECT found_rows() AS totalRows");
        $row=$st->fetch();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        return array($customers,$row['totalRows']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 1);

    }
}

public static function getcustomer($id){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="SELECT*FROM ".TBL_SALES."WHERE id=:id";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue("id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $row=$st->fetch();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        if($row) return new Customer($row);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 2);

    }
}

public function insert(){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".TBL_SALES."(
        customerName,
        totalPrice,
        date)VALUES(
        :customerName,
        :totalPrice,
        :NOW()
        )";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":customerName",$this->data["customerName"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue(":totalPrice",$this->data["totalPrice"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        //$st->bindValue(":date",$this->data["date"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 9);

    }
}
}

 ?>
```

And this is company.class.php file:

```
      <?php 
     require_once("DataObject.class.php");

       class Company extends DataObject{
      protected $data=array(
    'id'=>'',
    'companyName'=>'',
    'purchase'=>'',
    'date'=>''
    );

public static function getCompanies($startRow,$numRows,$order){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS*FROM ".TBL_PURCHASE." ORDER BY $order LIMIT :startRow, :numRows";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":startRow",$startRow,PDO::PARARM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(":numRows",$numRows,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $purchases=array();
        foreach($st->fetchAll() as $row){
            $companies[]=new Company($row);
        }
        $st=$conn->query("SELECT found_rows() AS totalRows");
        $row=$st->fetch();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        return array($companies,$row['totalRows']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 1);

    }
}

public static function getcompany($id){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="SELECT*FROM ".TBL_PURCHASE."WHERE id=:id";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue("id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $row=$st->fetch();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        if($row) return new Company($row);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 2);

    }
}

public function insert(){
    $conn=parent::connect();
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".TBL_PURCHASE."(
        companyName,
        purchase,
        date)VALUES(
        :companyName,
        :purchase,
        NOW()
        )";
    try {
        $st=$conn->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(":companyName",$this->data["companyName"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue(":purchase",$this->data["purchase"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->bindValue(":date",$this->data["date"],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->execute();
        parent::disconnect($conn);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        parent::disconnect($conn);
        throw new Exception("Error Processing Query Request", 3);

    }
}

 }

  ?>
```

this is purchase.php this work fine with company.class.php and input data into mysql database

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

require_once("company.class.php");


 if(isset($_POST["action"]) and $_POST["action"]=="add"){
 companyProcessForm();
} else{
companyForm(array(),array(),new Company(array()));
 }

  function companyForm($errorMessages,$missingFields,$company){

  if($errorMessages){
       foreach($errorMessages as $errorMessage){
          echo $errorMessage;
      }
    }else{

     ?>
  <form action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
       <div style="width:30em;">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">
        <label for="companyName"<?php validateField("companyName",$missingFields)?>>Company Name*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" value="<?php echo $company->getValueEncoded('companyName')?>">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="purchase"<?php if($missingFields) echo 'class="error"'?>>Purchase(Taka)</label>
    <input type="text"name="purchase"id="purchase"value="">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="add">
</div>

</form>
<?php 
   }
  }
 function companyProcessForm(){
   $missingFields=array();
   $errorMessages=array();
   $company=new Company(array(
    "companyName"=>isset($_POST["companyName"])? preg_replace("/[^ \-\_a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST["companyName"]):"",
    "purchase"=>isset($_POST["purchase"])? preg_replace("/[^\.\ 0-9]/", "", $_POST["purchase"]):""
    // "date"=>mow()
    ));
if($missingFields){
    $errorMessages[]='<p class="error">Please fill up all fields highlighted below.<p>';
}
if($errorMessages){
    companyForm($errorMessages,$missingFields,$company);
    // header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $company->insert();
    header("Location: index.php");
  }
  }
  ?>
```

this is index.php

```
<?php
 ob_start();
 require_once("common.inc.php");
 require_once("config.php");

 displayPageHeader("Purchase/Sales Report");

 include("purchase.php");

 displayPageFooter();

  ?>
```

this is sales.php

```
<?php

 require_once("config.php");
 require_once("customer.class.php");

 if(isset($_POST["action"]) and $_POST["action"]=="submit"){
  customerProcessForm();
  } else{
 customerForm(array(),array(),new Customer(array()));
  }

 function customerForm($errorMessages,$missingFields,$customer){

  if($errorMessages){
     foreach($errorMessages as $errorMessage){
         echo $errorMessage;
     }
  }else{
  ?>
<form action="index.php" method="post" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
    <div style="width:30em;">
    <div style="width:30em;">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    <label for="customerName"<?php validateField("customerName",$missingFields)?>>Customer Name*:</label>
    <input type="text" name="customerName" id="customerName" value="<?php echo $customer->getValueEncoded('customerName')?>">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="totalPrice"<?php if($missingFields) echo 'class="error"'?>>Total Price(Taka)</label>
    <input type="text"name="totalPrice"id="totalPrice"value="">
</div>
<div style="clear:both;">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="submit">
</div>

   </form>
   <?php } } 

  function customerrocessForm(){
$missingFields=array();
$errorMessages=array();
$customer=new Customer(array(
    "customerName"=>isset($_POST["customerName"])? preg_replace("/[^ \-\_a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST["customerName"]):"",
    "totalPrice"=>isset($_POST["totalPrice"])? preg_replace("/[^\.\ 0-9]/", "", $_POST["totalPrice"]):"",
    // "date"=>mow()
    ));
if($missingFields){
    $errorMessages[]='<p class="error">Please fill up all fields highlighted below.<p>';
}
if($errorMessages){
    customerForm($errorMessages,$missingFields,$customer);

}else{
    $customer->insert();
    header("Location: sales_report.php");
  }

 }

  ?>
```

and this slase_report.php when I input data it redirect me index.php and nothing input into mysql table sales. Also it does not work with customer.class.php show company.class.php uncaught exception on company.class.php insert function

```
     <?php
       ob_start();
       require_once("common.inc.php");
       require_once("config.php");
       require_once('customer.class.php');

     displayPageHeader("Sales Report");
      include("sales.php");
      displayPageFooter();

       ?>
```

the error is:

> [Sun Jan 03 12:15:52.564636 2016] [:error] [pid 4252] [client ::1:60871] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error Processing Query Request' in /var/www/html/salesReport/company.class.php:71\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/salesReport/purchase.php(57): Company->insert()\n#1 /var/www/html/salesReport/purchase.php(10): companyProcessForm()\n#2 /var/www/html/salesReport/index.php(8): include('/var/www/html/s...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/salesReport/company.class.php on line 71, referer: http://localhost/salesReport/sales_report.php 
>   `

```
 `
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what _exactly_ does that "uncaught exception" name as its cause?

Comment: And also: what does your http servers error log file show?

Comment: this is error  [Sun Jan 03 12:15:52.564636 2016] [:error] [pid 4252] [client ::1:60871] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error Processing Query Request' in /var/www/html/salesReport/company.class.php:71\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/salesReport/purchase.php(57): Company->insert()\n#1 /var/www/html/salesReport/purchase.php(10): companyProcessForm()\n#2 /var/www/html/salesReport/index.php(8): include('/var/www/html/s...')\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/salesReport/company.class.php on line 71, referer: http://localhost/salesReport/salereport.php

Comment: Well, you can see that this class catches an exception and throws the above exception in turn. So it basically _hides_ the valuable information given in the caught exception. _Why?_ Instead take a look into that caught exception, it tells you what is wrong!

Comment: thanks for reply. I am newbie in php and try this out. as fact my customer.class.php should work for sales_report. But it comes with company.class.php. and sales_report does not redirect instead index.php. Actually I do not get it properly.

Comment: That is all fine, but not the issue at hand. You have a specific exception. If you look where that is thrown (it tells you so...), then you see what I mentioned above. As said: look into the original exception that is caught (for example dump it inside the `catch(){}` block or remove that block completely to see what information _that_ original exception offers. You are interested in that information, you should not hide it like you do.